# Problem with symfony/var-dumper in composer.lock

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've got a problem with my `composer.lock` when I launch my `composer install`.

I've got an error :

> Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v4.0.12 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v4.0.12].

So I remove this from my `composer.lock`:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/var-dumper",
    "version": "v4.0.12",
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper.git",
        "reference": "f670984c74fa1e92e68c6e50fe9eebc3fc4d1923"
    },
    "dist": {
        "type": "zip",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/var-dumper/zipball/f670984c74fa1e92e68c6e50fe9eebc3fc4d1923",
        "reference": "f670984c74fa1e92e68c6e50fe9eebc3fc4d1923",
        "shasum": ""
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "~1.5"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "<4.8.35|<5.4.3,>=5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.34|~2.4"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-iconv": "To convert non-UTF-8 strings to UTF-8 (or symfony/polyfill-iconv in case ext-iconv cannot be used).",
        "ext-intl": "To show region name in time zone dump"
    },
    "type": "library",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "4.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Symfony\\Component\\VarDumper\\": ""
        },
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "/Tests/"
        ]
    },
    "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
    "license": [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nicolas Grekas",
            "email": "p@tchwork.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables",
    "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
    "keywords": [
        "debug",
        "dump"
    ],
    "time": "2018-06-15 07:52:13"
}
```

And everything works in the `composer install` command!

So, the question is ..... Why I've got this problem when I put it on my composer.lock? It was a good practice to remove it or not? Can I solve it with another solution?

Notice: I'm with PHP7.1.17 and Symfony3.3.

Comment: What is the contents of your `composer.json` file and what is the full error that you got when running `composer install`?

Comment: You should use composer update.

Comment: you should post the full error message - i bet there is more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to change contents of `composer.lock` file. you just set your [version constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) on `composer.json` and with `composer install`, you let composer resolve dependencies for you.

`composer.lock` is created automatically by composer and you should leave it unchanged.

If you have problems with `composer.lock` and your are developing in your own (you have not any collaborators), then you may simply remove `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` again.